# C++ Program crashes when reading binary data from file of X length

Tags: c++, file, binary, fstream

I am trying to read binary data from a file, here is my file structure:

```
#define SIGNATURE_LENGTH 3
#define VERSION_LENGTH 2
#define DATACOUNT_LENGTH 4
#define COMPRESS_LENGTH 1
#define FORMAT_LENGTH 2
#define DATALENGTH_LENGTH 4

const unsigned char resSignature[SIGNATURE_LENGTH] = { 0x52, 0x45, 0x53 };
const unsigned char resVersion[VERSION_LENGTH] = { 0x01, 0x00 };

const unsigned char isCompressed[COMPRESS_LENGTH] = { 0x01 };
const unsigned char notCompressed[COMPRESS_LENGTH] = { 0x00 };

// Data Formats:
const unsigned char dataUnknown[FORMAT_LENGTH] = { 0x00, 0x00 };
const unsigned char dataXML[FORMAT_LENGTH] = { 0x01, 0x00 };


// Define header structure for resource file
struct ResHeader
{
    unsigned char signature[SIGNATURE_LENGTH];
    unsigned char version[VERSION_LENGTH];
};

// Define data structure for resource file
struct ResData
{
    unsigned char compressed[COMPRESS_LENGTH];
    unsigned char dataFormat[FORMAT_LENGTH];
    unsigned char dataLength[DATALENGTH_LENGTH];
    unsigned char *data;
};
```

And my class uses:

```
std::fstream File;

// Resource file makeup
ResHeader  header;
unsigned char dataCount[DATACOUNT_LENGTH];

// Vector to contain resource file data
std::vector<ResData> ResourceData;
```

The program crashes when I try to read from a file:

```
int ResourceFile::LoadFile()
{
    File.open("blah.dat", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

    // Read header
    File.read((char*) header.signature, SIGNATURE_LENGTH);
    File.read((char*) header.version, VERSION_LENGTH);
    if(!VerifyHeader())
    {
        File.close();
        return HEADER_INCORRECT;
    }
    File.read((char*) dataCount, DATACOUNT_LENGTH);
    long fileCount = unsignedCharArrayToLong(dataCount);
    for(long i = 0; i < fileCount; ++i)
    {
        ResData tmp;
        File.read((char*) tmp.compressed, COMPRESS_LENGTH);
        File.read((char*) tmp.dataFormat, FORMAT_LENGTH);
        File.read((char*) tmp.dataLength, DATALENGTH_LENGTH);
        File.read((char*) tmp.data, unsignedCharArrayToLong(tmp.dataLength));
        ResourceData.push_back(tmp);
    }
    File.close();
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

The program crashes on the line:

```
File.read((char*) tmp.data, unsignedCharArrayToLong(tmp.dataLength));
```

The length of the data in the file is 282, which is what is read into tmp.dataLength; so the number is accurate.  The data is also compressed using easy zlib: http://www.firstobject.com/easy-zlib-c++-xml-compression.htm

Any suggestions/help as to what I am doing wrong or what I could be doing better would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Check if your file is null

Comment: Check if `tmp.data` is null (or otherwise undefined)...

Comment: What is the result of `unsignedCharArrayToLong(tmp.dataLength)`? Also, where do you allocate `data`?

Comment: if(!File) does not cause an error, nor does if(tmp.data == NULL)

Comment: @thomas: which is why I said "or otherwise undefined". See Mat's answer which explains it in detail.

Comment: std::cout << "dataLength: " << unsignedCharArrayToLong(tmp.dataLength);returns 282.  Right now I don't allocate tmp.data to anything other than creating the struct

Comment: sorry I didn't understand what you meant by otherwise undefined, but I see what you mean now.

Comment: By "not allocating" tmp.data, it points at some arbitrary place in memory. Since there are about 4 billion of those places in a 32-bit memory architecture, and at most your program takes up a few megabytes - most of which is not writeable, chances are about 1 in 1000 that your "arbitrary" memory address is "bad", causing it to crash. It's a bit like throwing darts behind your back. If you are lucky, you hit the dart-board, if you are VERY lucky, you hit treble 20. Most of the time, you don't hit anything other than the wall...

Comment: 282 is not a multiple of 4 (or 8), so `unsignedCharArrayToLong()` might have a little bit of an issue at the end of your buffer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This local variable:

```
ResData tmp;
```

contains

```
unsigned char *data;
```

Given that none of the code actually assigns anything to `data`, it will be pointing at some "random" place in memory. Which means "undefined behaviour", and given the law of averages and your result, in this case "undefined behaviour" means your program crashes, which is probably better than the alternative, or you would have been scratching your head a lot more when it went wrong somewhere else.

You probably want something like this (after the read for `dataLength`):

```
size_t len = unsignedCharArrayToLong(tmp.dataLength); 

tmp.data = new unsigned char[len];
File.read((char*) tmp.data, len);
```

Later on, don't forget to deallocate the data. Or better yet, use a `std::vector`, and instead of the call to new, do `data.resize(len);` and use `tmp.data.data()` to get the address of the buffer in the `File.read(...)`. That way, you don't need to remember to deallocate anything, because the `std::vector` will do it for you.

Comment: Awesome that worked great!  Thank you very much.  I'll be sure to delete it when I no longer need it.  I considered just using a vector to read all the data in and extract what I need from that, right now just trying to understand how all this works.  Appreciate the suggestion and will definitely consider that route :)

Comment: @thomas You should definitely consider using a `vector`. Contrary to common misconceptions, in C++ you should hardly ever use `new` and *never* use `delete`: RAII is here to manage memory automatically. `vector` or other STL containers are just a form of RAII, like smart pointers and other stuff which manage resources in your stead.

Comment: @syam Yeah I love vectors and have far more experience with them than arrays.  But as I've been googling on how to do binary file stuff most of it is done in the way I am here.  But one question is, in a lot of code, in destructors, there is usually code to empty vectors, to iterate through it and perform delete on each time, so is that unnecessary?  Does vector automatically delete when it is destroyed or falls out of scope?

Comment: If the vector is storing a pointer to some data, yes, you need to delete the content. If you're storing a `shared_pointer<T>` or `unique_ptr<T>` or something similar, then no, you don't need to do that. (In this case, you are storing a plain char, which doesn't need deleting).